# Etc hosts www.example.com to localhost?

Tags: windows, hosts

```
127.0.0.1     example.com www.example.com
```

It is work for example.com but don't work for 
www.example.com .
How to do setting for this problem that work all address Even for sites available on the Internet?

Comment: Add two entries.

Comment: try to do a `nslookup example.com` on your command line. if it still points somewhere you didnt want, or simply cant be resolved, fire up `ipconfig /flushdns` to clear windows dns cache. `host` file should be preferred over network-provided dns resolution. also, this question is more on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).